# Bypass modem and reach router

Tags: networking, internet, modem

I got this question running on my mind.

Basically my office network is setup in such a way that the ISP is connected to a modem(192.168.1.1) and the **lan** port of the modem is connected to the **wan** port of router(192.168.0.X). So when i type in my external ip on a browser my modem's login page open's up. So here istead of the modem I wanna make my router reachable when I access my external ip in a browser but still ISP needs to be connected to the modem. In other words I need to bypass my modem and connect to my router/router network directly

I need this to be setup so that I could setup a VPN on the 192.168.0.x subnet.

Please let me know if you require more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not connecting to the ISP side of the modem.  You need to contact your ISP to find out what the WAN side of the modem is addressed as.  Connect to that IP, and it should go to your router as it should.